# Построение маршрута на карте по пройденному пути

Tags: java, android, map

Нужно проложить маршрут из списка на гугл карте. Пример: 3 шага направо, 2 вперед, 1 налево и тд.
Сколько в цифрах 1 метр на карте?
Как это реализовать? Может быть есть готовые формулы?

У меня есть библиотека которая строит маршрут на гугл карате по точкам lat lng. Мне нужно просто перевести маршрут в координаты, Вся система работает офлайн
Мне кажется для моей ситуации достаточно просто узнать сколько например 1 метр вврех в долготе например 0.000004 0.000000 -> 0.000007 0.000000

Comment: на сколько помню, транспортное `API` платное.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно использовать [Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=ru#Waypoints)

Вы наверное говорите про формулу [расстояния на эллипсоиде](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance), но в данном случае она вам мало чем поможет, поскольку вы работаете с маршрутизацией, а внутри неё какого-то рода граф.

Самый простой вариант - использовать Google Direction API.

Comment: У меня есть библиотека которая строит маршрут на гугл карате по точкам   lat lng. Мне нужно просто перевести маршрут в координаты, Вся система работает офлайн